# What is Jango Fett's relation to the Death Watch in Disney Canon?

Tags: star-wars, character-similarity

In Legends canon, the Death Watch was a rogue faction of Mandalorians who had rejected the Mandalorian standards of honor and were notorious for their brutality. They were directly responsible for the death of Jango Fett's family, thus leading to his adoption by Jaster Mereel. It is also established that Mandalorian armor is more or less the same design, but customized by each warrior and therefore different colors according to individual taste. In Jango Fett's case, he inherited Jaster's blue & silver armor when the older man was killed in battle. He then discarded his old green armor for the blue & silver set to honor his adopted father.

---

In the new Disney canon, however, the Death Watch is a rogue political faction that rejects the pacifist policies of Duchess Satine of Mandalore. The relationship with Jango Fett is not mentioned, but all members of Death Watch can be seen wearing armor nearly identical to that of Jango Fett, with the "normal" Mandalorians wearing a slightly different design of armor.

[image]

So this leaves me with the question of why Jango Fett was wearing what, in effect, was a Death Watch uniform when he should have been wearing a different style of armor altogether. Or maybe it's been explained that the armor is an older style favored by old-school Mandalorians, but I must have missed that part if so.

**In the new Disney canon, what is the relationship (if any) between Jango Fett and the rogue Death Watch faction on Mandalore?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### None that's been revealed

About all we know about Jango Fett's history in the new canon is that he isn't a Mandalorian; Pablo Hidalgo confirmed as much [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/693214698003644417) in early 2016:

[image]

> **@pablohidalgo:** The Fetts aren't Mandalorian, though I suppose Jango claimed to be from Concord Dawn at some point.

Almec, then-Prime Minister of Mandalore, reiterates Fett's non-Mandalorian heritage in "The Mandalore Plot", an episode of *The Clone Wars*:

> **Obi-Wan:** I recently encountered a man who wore Mandalorian armor: Jango Fett.
>
> **Almec:** Jango Fett was a common bounty hunter. How he acquired that armour is beyond me.
>
> <sup>*Star Wars: The Clone Wars* Season 2 Episode 12: "The Mandalore Plot"</sup>

It's doubtful he was a member of Death Watch, who seem to be an exclusively-Mandalorian<sup>1</sup> group, but it doesn't mean he wasn't affiliated with them in some capacity; what sort of affiliation that could be is, at time of writing, unknown.

Where he got his Mandalorian armour, and why he uses it, has yet to be revealed in the new canon.

---

<sup>1</sup> In contrast to Legends, where the Mandalorians were an equal-opportunity, multi-species group, the Mandalorians in the new Canon seem to exclusively be natives of the planet Mandalore and her colonies (including Concord Dawn)

Comment: Brings up an interesting side question: Is a tweet from someone other than Lucas considered higher canon than Legends? For that matter, would even a tweet from Lucas be canon now that Disney owns the franchise? Whoa... now my head hurts.

Comment: @Omegacron For behind-the-scenes stuff, Lucas is probably still reliable; not for new canon though. But Hidalgo and the LSG are as close as you can get to "word of god", so I guess it depends on your opinion on that; some people don't like it, some do

Comment: Footnote 1 may have changed with The Mandalorian series.  Din Djarin seems to have been rescued and taken in by Death Watch.  Foundlings in the show harken back to the Legends multi-species, Mandalorian-as-long-as-you-follow-the-six-actions inclusiveness.

Answer (score 0):

One of the big clans in the Mandalorian’s history is Clan Fett. A familiar character from the Old Republic during the Mandalorian Wars is Cassus Fett. Whatever happened to the clan up until the Clone Wars is a mystery to me. But I can assure you Jango Fett is Mandalorian. Concord Dawn itself is a Mandalorian colony, if I remember correctly.

And no he wasn’t affiliated with Death Watch either. He was a member of the True Mandalorians. These Mandalorians unlike the New Mandalorians werent pacifists, nor were they savage raiders like the Death Watch. They were honorable mercaneries that went by a code created by Jaster Mareel when he became Mandalore. The Death Watch were a splinter group that didnt agree with these rules and went to war with the True Mandalorians. Jango Fett’s family was caught in the crossfire which is what lead to their fate and to Jango being adopted by Jaster

As for Jango’s armor, his armor was green but when the True Mandalorians where annihalated and Jango was sold into slavery, the govenor of the planet that sheltered the Death Watch kept Jango’s armor and had it refurbished and painted to its blue and silver look. When jango escaped he reclaimed his brand-spanking new-looking armor and took revenge on Tar Vizsla.

[image]

Comment: Hi Yoshi, welcome to Sci Fi Stack Exchange! Do you have a source for this?

Comment: I've pasted the text from your other answers into this one since only one answer is necessary. While this is an attempt to answer the question, this is Legends information and the question is looking for information from canon.